# CSS not working in PHP script

Tags: php, css

I have a problem with my script. The script prints the numbers 1 to 100 in black font. For multiples of 3, it prints the word "Three" in green, and for multiples of 7, prints the word "Seven" in blue instead of the number. If the number is a multiple of BOTH 3 and 7, then print the word "Both" in red.

Problem that i am having is that its only printing Three in green, not printing Seven in blue and Both in red. Not sure what i am doing wrong.

Here is my css

```
<style type="text/css">
.three{ color:green};
.seven{ color:blue};
.both { color:red};
</style>
```

below is my PHP

```
<?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
        if ($i % 3 == 0 && $i % 7 == 0) {
            print '<p class="both" >' . "Both<br />" . '</p>';
        } else if ($i % 3 == 0) {
            print '<p class="three" >' . "Three<br />" . '</p>';
        } else if ($i % 7 == 0) {
            print '<p class="seven" >' . "Seven<br />" . '</p>';
        } else {
            print $i . "<br />";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: The logic seems to be right. Lets update with the HTML output.

Comment: Instead of css have you tried doing inline styling for debugging purposes?e.g. <p class="seven" style="color:red"<p>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just put like this your problem will solve

```
<style type="text/css">
.three{ color:green}
.seven{ color:blue}
.both { color:red}
</style>
```

Also for both class put like below

```
print '<p class="both" >'."Both<br />". '</p>';
```

remove `\ \` from print statement and try.

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: The semicolon is needed inside the brackets.

Comment: Additionally, the semicolon should be inside the braces `.three{ color: green; }`.  It's optional, but I just prefer it that way.

Comment: @Gimmy No ending semicolon is needed

Answer (score 8):

change style to this. This will work:

```
<style type="text/css">
.three{ color:green;}
.seven{ color:blue;}
.both { color:red;}
</style>
```

problem is in semicolon(;)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with your CSS. Improper placement of the `;` semicolon.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .three {color: green;}
    .seven {color: blue;}
    .both  {color: red;}
</style>
```

Also, you can remove the `\"` in both.

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS isn't valid.

Change to this:

```
<style>
.three{ color:green;}
.seven{ color:blue;}
.both { color:red;}
</style>
```